# C++ Templates: Inlined code and Compiler Optimzations

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-optimization

Is it safe to assume that the following code when optimized and inlined by the compiler would remove the branch needed to evaluate the ternary operation? Or with most mainstream compilers would it be wiser to break the method below into two separate methods to avoid the branch?

```
/*! \brief this method returns the cos of an angle. User can specify if it is
 * in degrees or radians.
 */
template <typename T, angle_mode AM>
T cos(const T &angle)
{ 
  return (AM == radians) ? 
    std::cos(angle) :
    std::cos(degrees_to_radians(angle));
}
```

Comment: It really does depend on how you are using it.  Optimization will only work if AM is a constant.  If AM is a variable, then there is no way of optimizing anything out.

Comment: Your disassembly doesn't seem related to the question.  Your first snippet is `degrees_to_radians()` (which has no comparisons but does call another function) and your second snippet is `main` where the branch you mention appears to be part of the inlined version of `glext2pi()`.  Your test of `AM` is long gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that should always be optimized out.

Even if it wasn't, I have a feeling that the cost of `std::cos` would greatly overshadow the cost of the conditional.

If for some reason it's not being optimized, use template specialization to force the branch at compile-time.

Comment: @MatthewHoggan I'm pretty bad at reading assembly, especially this late at night. Have you compared it to a version with separate functions and no branch?

Comment: No I have not I have pushed forward in my work, but I hope to revisit this tomorrow.